# Dynamics of a particle moving in a Straight line (Lift Problems)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration

> A woman of mass $60 kg$ is in a lift which is accelerating upwards at a rate of $ 2ms^{-2}.$
>
> Find the magnitude of the normal reaction of the floor of the lift on the woman.

I would now like to illustrate my thought process for this problem and would like someone to explain to me why this is incorrect.

A: Defining upwards as postive

$$ R - mg = 0 $$

Where $R$ is the normal reaction force and $mg$ is weight of the woman due to gravity.

The reason why I have equated $R-mg$ to $0$ is because the woman is stationary in the lift, I would think that if we were to equate it to $60 \times 2 $ then we would need to consider the other forces such as the weight of the lift.

**What I am trying to say in my above statement is that, if the lift is travelling with an acceleration of $2ms^{-2}$ and no other forces are given then the only forces making this lift accelerate is the weight of woman and the weight of the lift, therefore equating $R-W_{woman} = 60 \times 2 $ would be incorrect as this is not the complete set of forces making the lift accelerate!**

Could someone explain why this is incorrect thinking?

Comment: What is the acceleration of the woman? Hence, by Newton’s 2nd law, what must be the total force on the woman?

Comment: pl. put the woman on a weighing machine inside the lift.then a correct reading for normal reaction may  be obtained.

Comment: "therefore equating R−Wwoman=60×2  would be incorrect as this is not the complete set of forces making the **lift** accelerate!" Why are you considering the forces on the **lift**? You wrote that equation for the **woman**! ;)

Comment: You are missing that woman is also accelerating upwards with 2m/s^2 as correctly  answered by Rodney Dunning

Answer (score 1):

You need only consider the forces acting on the woman herself. There are two: the normal force ($R$), directed upward and provided by the floor of the lift, and her weight ($mg$), directed downward and provided by the Earth's gravitational field. The sum of these forces yields the net force acting on her, which is the force responsible for her acceleration of 2 m/s$^{2}$. So we may write:

$$R - mg = ma,$$

where $m$ is her mass and $a$ is her acceleration. Solving for $R$, we get

$$R = ma + mg = m(a + g).$$

$$R = (60\text{ }\mathrm{kg})(2 \text{ }\textrm{m/s}^{2} + 9.8 \text{ }\textrm{m/s}^{2}) = 708 \text{ }\mathrm{N}.$$

If she is standing on a scale, it will read $708$ N.

Comment: Generally a scale doesn't read it in Newton . I think it will read 708/9.8